# Recycleviewer Adapter NotifyDataSetChanged not work?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, android-viewpager, pagertabstrip

I'm using PagerSlidingTabStrip for create tabs and in each tab i have `Recyclerview` to poupulate related tab items . for example we have 3 tabs with names of Toyota , Benz and Ford and A tab tho show All of items, so in Toyota tab we have vehicles of it and so on. `Recyclerview` items have a button for add to cart and remove from cart and a `Textview` to show the number of order .Remove button and `Textview` is hidden by default and when user add an item to cart so remove button and `Textview` visiblility will true . The problems is that if a user adds an item to the cart then Remove button and `Textview` of related item is not Visible in All tab?! But in All tab when user add an item to cart it reflected to item in related tab. I think the problem is the Adapter of `Recylerview` , it holds the view and not refresh the tab of All items , maybe .I use `NotifyDataSetChanged` of `Recyclerview` Adapter but not work.

The `button` to add to cart and remove: mDecremtBtn and mIncrementBtn when clicked visible `Textview` and decrement button.

```
mDcrementBtn.Click += delegate
                    {

                        if (orderList.Count == 0)
                        {
                            quntitySum = 0;
                        }

                        //Find order and decrement
                        var orderItem = orderList.Find(p => p.FoodId == foodId);
                        orderItem.Quantity--;
                        _quantitiyTxt.Text = orderItem.Quantity.ToString();

                        if (orderItem.Quantity == 0)
                        {
                            mDcrementBtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                            _quantitiyTxt.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                            _quantitiyTxt.Text = "";
                            orderList.Remove(orderItem);
                        }
                        if (orderList.Count == 0)
                        {
                            _fabCart.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

                            //Update bageNotification On bottomNavigation Cart when no items in orderlist
                            _badgeNotification.Text = "";
                            _badgeNotification.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                        }
                        _fabCart.SetImageBitmap(ConvertTextToBitmap.TextAsBitmap((--quntitySum).ToString(), 36,
                           Color.White));

                        //Update bageNotification On bottomNavigation Cart
                        _badgeNotification.Text = quntitySum.ToString();
                        _adpter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                    };

                    mIncrementBtn.Click += delegate
                    {
                        if (orderList.Count == 0)
                        {
                            quntitySum = 0;
                        }
                        _fabCart.Show();
                        mDcrementBtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                        _quantitiyTxt.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                        if (orderList.Any(p => p.FoodId == foodId))
                        {
                            //Find order and increment
                            var orderItem = orderList.Find(p => p.FoodId == foodId);

                            orderItem.Quantity++;
                            _quantitiyTxt.Text = orderItem.Quantity.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            orDetail = new Order
                            {
                                FoodId = foodId,
                                FoodName = mFoodNameTxt.Text,
                                Price = Convert.ToInt32(mPriceTxt.Text),
                                ClickFlag = true
                            };

                            orDetail.Quantity++;
                            orderList.Add(orDetail);
                            _quantitiyTxt.Text = orDetail.Quantity.ToString();
                        }

                        _fabCart.SetImageBitmap(ConvertTextToBitmap.TextAsBitmap((++quntitySum).ToString(), 36,
                            Color.White));

                        //Update bageNotification On bottomNavigation Cart
                        _badgeNotification.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                        _badgeNotification.Text = quntitySum.ToString();

                        _adpter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                    };
```

In OnbindeViewHolder of class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter items are update.

```
public override  void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
                {
                    var simpleHolder = holder as SimpleViewHolder;    

                    simpleHolder.mFoodNameTxt.Text = _foodItems[position].FoodName;
                    simpleHolder.mPriceTxt.Text = _foodItems[position].Price.ToString();
                    simpleHolder.foodId = _foodItems[position].Id;   

                    var item = orderList.Find(p => p.FoodId == _foodItems[position].Id);
                    if (item != null && item.ClickFlag)
                    {
                        simpleHolder.mDcrementBtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                        simpleHolder._quantitiyTxt.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                        simpleHolder._quantitiyTxt.Text = item.Quantity.ToString();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        simpleHolder.mDcrementBtn.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                        simpleHolder._quantitiyTxt.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                        simpleHolder._quantitiyTxt.Text = "";
                    }

                }
```

The senario of it in Imagenary :
[image]

Compelete code in https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/120389/recycleviewer-adapter-notifydatasetchanged-not-work/p1?new=1

Comment: your qus is a little bit unclear , plz post pictures of the scenario ..

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat The pictures of the scenario  added. Thanks

Comment: you have to use single arrayList for that and whenever you add or remove the count of the product then only you have to notify the recyclerView . .as you'r using fragments in activity then you should create that list in activity . . . so that it can be access in all fragments

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat because All tab is in the first position (zero) so populate in adapter first of other tabs, the view of first tab (All) never change even with NotifyDataSetChanged. If user touch an item to Increment the order , DecrementBtn and Textview of order number visible and in related tab  also effected.But in other tabs change item not effect in All tab.

Comment: Hi, the link you provided in your post is your project code? I can't get in, I get this "You need the Vanilla.Discussions.Edit permission to do that."

Comment: @JoeLvMSFT Your right . Now Updated

Comment: Hi, It is difficult to read. Do you mind put your project on github?  So I can download and test it and find the problem fast.